# I moved from "Oh-My-Zsh" to "Starship" and wish to enable "url-quote-magic" module

Tags: zsh, macos

I switched from `oh-my-zsh` to `starship` and I find this tool much better.

The only thing that bothers me is that when I paste URI into the Terminal, they aren't automatically quoted. So `mpv` or `yt-dlp` can't do anything with the URI.

With `oh-my-zsh`, `url-quote-magic` was apparently enabled without doing anything.

I would now like to have `url-quote-magic` with `starship`. How-to to ingegrate `url-quote-magic` into `starship`?

```
brew search url-quote-magic
==> Downloading https://formulae.brew.sh/api/formula.json
######################################################################## 100.0%
Error: No formulae or casks found for "url-quote-magic".

zsh --version
zsh 5.8.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin22.0)
```

UPDATE:

The installation method from their Readme doesn't work

```
yt-dlp https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ii_lXjLFddA
zsh: no matches found: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ii_lXjLFddA

mpv https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=36YnV9STBqc
zsh: no matches found: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=36YnV9STBqc


cat .zshrc
eval "$(starship init zsh)"
source /opt/homebrew/share/zsh-autosuggestions/zsh-autosuggestions.zsh
autoload -Uz url-quote-magic
zle -N self-insert url-quote-magic
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://opensource.apple.com/source/zsh/zsh-65/zsh/Functions/Zle/url-quote-magic.auto.html), you just need to add the following lines to your zshrc:

```
autoload -Uz url-quote-magic
zle -N self-insert url-quote-magic
```

(I tested it on a Linux system and it seems to work for me. I use neither oh-my-zsh nor starship.)

If you have bracketed pasting enabled, you'll need [`bracketed-paste-magic`](https://opensource.apple.com/source/zsh/zsh-72/zsh/Functions/Zle/bracketed-paste-magic.auto.html):

```
autoload -Uz bracketed-paste-magic
zle -N bracketed-paste bracketed-paste-magic
```

Comment: Did you start a new shell after editing your zshrc?

Comment: 1) Can you run these commands in the shell directly and see if that works? 2) Does disabling starship make a difference?

Comment: @Sybil another though: bracketed pasting might be in effect, so also run `zle -N bracketed-paste bracketed-paste-magic`

Comment: @Sybil [bracketed paste is a security feature](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/39118/54387) where the shell doesn't interpret pasted data as if it were typed in, I'd recommend keeping it enabled. Since it affects pasted data, you need the extra configuration as this functionality is for pasting URLs.